# Oauth2 assertion grant: Why no refresh token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm looking into Oauth2 to allow developers to authorize users of their app to use my service. I've found a few sources that say that my Authorization Server should return an access token when a user sends an assertion (JWT in my case) but that it should not return a refresh token. I'm wondering what the harm is in returning a refresh token. Developers could invalidate refresh/access tokens by calling an Api that invalidates any access granted from a particular JWT's id.

Comment: With the [RFC7521](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7521), refresh tokens are useless as mentioned in [the section 4.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7521#section-4.1): *Clients can refresh an expired access token by requesting a new one using the same assertion, if it is still valid, or with a new assertion.*

Comment: I disagree that it's useless. I'm thinking of a client that is waking up after being inactive for a while. That client would have to ask its app server for a JWT and then trade that JWT for an access token. That's 2 round trips vs 1 round trip. Maybe that's not a big deal but there is a non-negligible performance implication here.

Comment: This is useless because the client can refresh it either by sending the same assertion (if not expired) or creating a new one. As it is normally generated on client side, then this is a 1 round.

Comment: Oh yes, I was taking for granted that the assertion would be short-lived. It has identifiable information in it so clients should not store it. I should have mentioned this earlier.

Answer (score 1):

That recommendation is not correct. Refresh tokens are optional and can be issued at the discretion of the Authorization Server after client presents the authorization grant. See [Oauth2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-10)

> **1.5 Refresh tokens**

> Refresh tokens are credentials used to obtain access tokens.  Refresh
> tokens are issued to the client by the authorization server and are
> used to obtain a new access token when the current access token
> becomes invalid or expires, or to obtain additional access tokens
> with identical or narrower scope (access tokens may have a shorter
> lifetime and fewer permissions than authorized by the resource
> owner).  **Issuing a refresh token is optional at the discretion of the
> authorization server.  If the authorization server issues a refresh
> token, it is included when issuing an access token** (i.e., step (D) in
> Figure 1).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I rechecked the source that I read that made me question this. It turns out it's more of an observation than a recommendation. It says you usually don't give a refresh token in an assertion grant flow. I guess I'm just wondering if I'm missing a disadvantage here. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7521

Comment: May be it is talking about the different Authorization Grant flows in Oauth2.0 to get an access token. The "Authorization Code Grant" provides an authorization code where in a second step you can get an access/refresh token. The "Implicit Grant" flow provides an access token in one step, and does not allow to use refresh tokens